# Azure Streaming Analytics output to azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics

When an azure function output from stream analytics receives a 500 error will the events stop until the retries get a successful response? I already have partition ordering setup (needed in this case) but i cant have events process out of order.

Example

Event A gets into event hub

Event A goes to stream analytics

Event B gets into event hub

Event A goes to azure function output

Event A in azure functions fails and returned 500

Event B what happens here with Event B

Or does streaming analytics read off the partition bookmark and until it successfully sends to all outputs it wont read again?

Answer (score 0):

Is event b from a different partition? If so, it should not be blocked by event A being retried. In which case the order will be different. Event B will be written and then event A will eventually be posted if the exception is transient.